# How do I write this regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, hashmap

I have a string like so:

```
"\"john smith\" <jsmith@gmail.com>, \"joe@gmail.com\" <joe@gmail.com>"
```

what I need is a ruby Hash that looks like:

```
{ 'john smith' => 'jsmith@gmail.com', 'joe@gmail.com => 'joe@gmail.com' }
```

How would I use regex to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Hash[str.scan(/"(.*?)" <(.*?)>/)]
# => {"john smith"=>"jsmith@gmail.com", "joe@gmail.com"=>"joe@gmail.com"}
```